# JavaScript: functions passed as a parameter to an if block

Tags: javascript, function

In the below code how does passing bar as

```
 function (n) { return n; }
```

to foo evaluate to true in the if block?

```
 function foo(bar) {

    if (bar) {
       // true
    } else {
       // false
    }
 }
```

This has me puzzled so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `bar` is bound to an anonymous function, then it is an object. Objects are 'truthy' in JavaScript.

The only values in JavaScript that are 'falsy' are:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `''` (empty string)
- `0` (zero as a number)
- `NaN`

Everything else is 'truthy', including function objects.

If you meant to call the anonymous function, you'd do `if (bar(5))` which would call your anonymous function with the argument `5`. Then your anonymous function would return `n` (which is `5` in this case). As `5` is not a falsy object, this would go to the `true` branch as well. Doing `if (bar(0))` would got to the `else` branch, because `0` is falsy.

Comment: thanks for the answer, was most helpful for my more complicated example that the question is extracted from.

Comment: @Godders: More than happy to help :)

Answer (score 5):

Anything not `null`, `0`, `false`, empty string or `undefined` is going to evaluate to `true` in an `if(something)` statement, this is just how weak-typing in JavaScript works.

If you want more specificity you may want to look at the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator) to check for the type you're expecting, or use a another stronger check like this:

```
if(bar === true) {
```

Using `===` checks for both value *and* type equivalence.

Comment: thanks also for your answer, helpful too, if I could mark both as the answer I would!

Answer (score 0):

You could use typeof() if you want to know what type it returns

Comment: No, you can't.  Javascript functions do not have static return types.

Answer (score 0):

It always return true, because bar is not null. if an expression within an if statement is not a logic expression (e.g. if(x <7)) then performs a check for null. If it is null it returns false, otherwise true.

In your example you have defined bar as the function {returns n;} so that is why your if statement is evaluating to true.

If bar returns a bool (true or false) then you need to call the function and get the result, rather than passing a reference to the function - this is done using parentheses:

```
var exampleA = bar(false); // executes function bar and returns the result (false) in exampleA
var exampleB = bar; // stores a reference to the function bar in variable exampleB
```